# Ensuring a hash function is well-mixed with slicing

Tags: hash, language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, consistent-hashing

Forgive me if this question is silly, but I'm starting to learn about consistent hashing and after reading Tom White blog post on it [here](http://www.tom-e-white.com/2007/11/consistent-hashing.html) and realizing that most default hash functions are NOT well mixed I had a thought on ensuring that an arbitrary hash function is minimally well-mixed.

My thought is best explained using an example like this:

```
Bucket 1: 11000110
Bucket 2: 11001110
Bucket 3: 11010110
Bucket 4: 11011110
```

Under a standard hash ring implementation for consistent caching across these buckets, you would be get terribly performance, and nearly every entry would be lumped into Bucket 1. However, if we use bits 4&5 as the MSBs in each case then these buckets are suddenly excellently mixed, and assigning a new object to a cache becomes trivial and only requires examining 2 bits.

In my mind this concept could very easily be extended when building distributed networks across multiple nodes. In my particular case I would be using this to determine which cache to place a given piece of data into. The increased placement speed isn't a real concern, but ensuring that my caches are well-mixed is and I was considering just choosing a few bits that are optimally mixed for my given caches. Any information later indexed would be indexed on the basis of the same bits.

In my naive mind this is a much simpler solution than introducing virtual nodes or building a better hash function. That said, I can't see any mention of an approach like this and I'm concerned that in my hashing ignorance I'm doing something wrong here and I might be introducing unintended consequences.

Is this approach safe? Should I use it? Has this approach been used before and are there any established algorithms for determining the minimum unique group of bits?

Comment: You are essentially changing the hash function, from one that has more bits to one that has fewer bits (and only 4 buckets are possible). How can this possibly help? And how do you add a new fifth bucket? This seems to solve problems entirely different from what consistnet hashing is designed for.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I am not removing any bits, only re-arranging them. Adding a fifth bucket is done as usual. Not ignoring the other buckets, just changing the location of the bits.

Comment: *"Not ignoring the other buckets, just changing the location of the bits."* - and how do you plan to do that without having most existing objects start mapping to another cache?

Comment: @TonyD The idea was to do this at instantiation and have a fixed bit-flipping. Mapping to another cache is kind of the idea?

Comment: Mapping to another cache is only the idea for ~1/5th of the values - those that aren't assigned to the "fifth bucket" should retain their old assignment.  I don't see how your varied bit selection idea will maintain that relationship dynamically, and I don't see any point unless it's dynamic... you'll have lost all the attributes of *consistent* hashing.  Anyway, maybe you should implement whatever you have in mind so we're talking about concrete code and behaviours... then you can ask a more specific question if you have a specific issue but still think your idea can work.

Comment: I'm voting this as "unclear what you are asking" as you clearly don't specify the full algorithm, e.g. why everything would be put in bucket 1, and why specific bits would be more probable than others.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I suppose that's fair? My belief was that consistent hashing was a common enough algorithm that people would be familiar, answering the first question. As far as the second question is concerned that's a fundamental issue with all hashing algorithms. I suppose I could refer to a wikipedia article about hashing functions?

Comment: "Is it safe?" Well yes, but for perfect hashes you must check that it is unique. "Should I use it?" Up to you - subjective. "Has this approach been used before and are there any established algorithms for determining the minimum unique group of bits?" Impossible to answer negatively. But maybe your question fares better [at the CS site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). It's not really a programming question either (no language/runtime tags). I mean after more than 2 years I don't think people are familiar enough here.

Comment: I don't think the question would fare any better on the CS site, as this question is principally concerned with the practical considerations than the theoretical guarantees. I would also argue that the language-agnostic tag exists for a reason and not having a specific language is no better a reason to close this question than to close the other 7k questions that fit the same pattern.

I've got plenty of other old questions without responses. At the very least I've got some people asking reasonable questions on this one.